# wordpress - action hook 'pre publish post'?

Tags: php, wordpress

need to change post content before it is published. I could overwrite the native publish function but don't want to do this.

What i'd like to do is something like:

```
add_action('before_publish_post','my_func');
function my_func($content){
    $content = "new content";
    return $content;
}
```

I have had a look at the 'publish_post' hook, but this only allows me to change the post content afer it has been published, not before.

any help would be appreciated,
cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be the filter [`wp_insert_post_data`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data)

Answer (score 3):

If I was really cool I'd wait until the Anniversary date of this post & do it then, but...

It's also possible to use:

```
add_action('pre_post_update','alter_post_contents');
```

I'm coding an admin interface right now that will make use of this so I'll report on whether it was effective. I saw one other post here related to the use of `pre_post_update`, but it claims to make use of post id as the arg- and their *`post.php`* page seems to bear this out- whereas the codex states that content is the arg and that suits your purposes dead on....

Seems testing will show this one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) hook.

You can read more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either. 'save post' runs after the post is saved to the database.
My posts will have code in them that I need to str_replace before they get published (saved to the database).
I'm sure their has to be a way to capture the $_POST['content'] before it gets written to the datbase

Comment: Also if you have some other plugins save_post might called twice and more