# How to limit number of links per post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, limit

is there way how to limit number of links per post in Wordpress?
I know this can be done by one simple function but I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: I think the standard way is to put an if statement in the while loop and declare a variable before the while loop and increase the variable by one for each loop. Ending the loop if the number reaches a certain limit.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I need to say that I have almost no knowledge of PHP. I understand what you say but I don't know how and where to implement it.

Comment: When you say `how to limit number of links` are you talking about the links the author is allowed to place in a single post or the external links that can access that post.

Comment: I am talking about the links the author is allowed to place in a single post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the suggestions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058737/wordpress-action-hook-pre-publish-post)

You can count the number of `<a...></a>` tags by matching with a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! 
So I made simple plugin like this: http://pastebin.com/M8J2N4c4

But it still didnt work..